# How To Return number of duplicate string in the array list compare to another array list JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to return how many time does word duplicate if it is exist in the another `ArrayList`.

More Explanation: if a word in the first `ArrayList` exist in the another arrayList I wanna check how many times it duplicate in the second array List but it is not working?

```
public int Duplication(ArrayList<String> studentList, ArrayList<String> teacherList){
    Set<String> uniqueStudent = new HashSet<String>(studentList);
    Set<String> uniqueTeacher = new HashSet<String>(teacherList);

    for (String studentKey : uniqueStudent) {
        for (String teacherKey : uniqueTeacher) {
            if(teacherKey.equals(studentKey)){
                return Collections.frequency(studentList, studentKey);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why you need to verify teacherKey.equals(studentKey).Can you please explain

Comment: First of all -- your method shouldn't even compile: if teacherKey never equals studentKey, there's no path to a return statement. Second: you're going to return the first time you find a match--so you're only going to get the count the first time there's a duplicate.

Comment: so are you looking to know how many times each string in list one appears in list two? say list one has [word1, word2, word3] and list two has [word6, word1, word1, word1, word2] do you want to know word1 appeard 3 times and word 2 appeared 1 time?, if this is the case you need to return a HashMap with the word as the key and their number of occurences as value.... or do you just want to know how many times a specific word appears in list2. in that case its ok to return just an int

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public Map<String, Integer> Duplication(ArrayList<String> studentList, 
                                        ArrayList<String> teacherList) {
    Map<String, Integer> nameCount = new HashMap<>();
    for (String studentKey : new HashSet<>(studentList)) {
        nameCount.put(studentKey, Collections.frequency(teacherList, studentKey));
    }
    return nameCount;
}
```

Comment: the method signature returns an `int` but `nameCount` is a `map`... this will not compile

Comment: `nameCount` is not `int` it is `Map`.

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted and bit too quickly

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

> If you Just want a method which returns duplicate values refer this code below

```
public Map<String,Integer> duplicateCount(ArrayList<String> studentList, 
                       ArrayList<String> teachersList) {
    Map<String, Integer> duplicateCount = new HashMap<>();
    for (String studentKey : new HashSet<>(studentList)) {
        duplicateCount.put(studentKey, Collections.frequency(teacherList, studentKey));
    }
    return duplicateCount;
}
```

> If you want to  Finds out Duplicate and Unique Values in two lists and return gives the count of duplicate values.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
    List<String> studentList=new ArrayList<String>();
    //Put Dummy  values in Student List
    studentList.add("a");
    studentList.add("b");
    studentList.add("c");
    studentList.add("d");
    List<String> teacherList=new ArrayList<String>();
    //Put Dummy  values in Teacher List
    teacherList.add("a");
    teacherList.add("1");
    teacherList.add("c");
    teacherList.add("c");
    teacherList.add("c");
    teacherList.add("c");
    teacherList.add("c");
    teacherList.add("2");
    Set<String> uniqueStudent = new HashSet<String>(studentList);

    Set<String> uniqueTeacher = new HashSet<String>(teacherList);
    Set<String> duplicateValue= new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> uniqueValue= new HashSet<String>();
    uniqueStudent.retainAll(uniqueTeacher);
    duplicateValue=uniqueStudent; //As uniqueStudent Now has only the duplicate values due to above step assing this set to duplicateValue set
    uniqueStudent=new HashSet<String>(studentList);//reassign UniqueStudent Set
    uniqueStudent.removeAll(uniqueTeacher);
    uniqueValue=uniqueStudent;
    System.out.println("duplicateValue:"+duplicateValue);
    System.out.println("uniqueValue:"+uniqueValue);
    //Now Counting Occurance of Duplicate Values in Other List
    for(String duplicate:duplicateValue){
        int occurrences = Collections.frequency(teacherList, duplicate);
        System.out.println("Number of Occurance For "+duplicate+" is "+occurrences);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
> duplicateValue:[c, a]
> uniqueValue:[d, b]
> Number of Occurrence For c is 5
> Number of Occurrence For a is 1
```

> Explanation For The methods Used:

- Every `List` can take another list as a constructor parameter, and copy it's values.
- `retainAll(...)` will remove all entries, that does not exist in `...`.
- `removeAll(...)` will remove all entries, that does exist in `...`.
- We don't want to remove/retain on the original lists, because this will modify it, so we copy them, in the constructor.
- `Collections.frequency(--)` will give the frequency of occurrence of the word in list.

Comment: @Marco13 Initially I've added the answer just for explaining the steps. now updated it with working Code

Answer (score 0):

The right datastructure to store the duplicates is being considered as `Map` and below is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> duplicatesMap = duplicate(
            new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "A", "H",
                    "T", "P", "S", "O", "F", "X", "A" })),
            new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "A", "H",
                    "T", "P", "S", "O", "F", "A", "O", "B", "X", "R" })));
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : duplicatesMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " found " + entry.getValue()
                + " times");
    }
}

public static Map<String, Integer> duplicate(ArrayList<String> fromList,
        ArrayList<String> toList) {
    Map<String, Integer> returnMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Set<String> uniqueFromList = new HashSet<String>(fromList);
    for (String key : uniqueFromList) {
        if (toList.contains(key)) {
            returnMap.put(key, Collections.frequency(toList, key));
        }
    }
    return returnMap;
}
```

### Output

`T found 1 times
 F found 1 times
 A found 2 times
 P found 1 times
 S found 1 times
 O found 2 times
 H found 1 times
 X found 1 times`

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
public int Duplication(ArrayList<String> studentList, ArrayList<String> teacherList){
  Set<String> uniqueStudent = new HashSet<String>(studentList);
  Set<String> uniqueTeacher = new HashSet<String>(teacherList);

  int counter = 0;
  for (String studentKey : uniqueStudent) {
    if(uniqueTeacher.contains(studentKey)){
      for (String teacherKey : uniqueTeacher) {
         if(teacherKey.equals(studentKey)){
           counter ++;
         }
      }
    }
  }

  return counter;
}
```